# Remove all non contiguous records with identical fields

Tags: sql, sql-server

I got a table with some columns like

```
ID RecordID DateInserted

1   10     now + 1
2   10     now + 2
3   4      now + 3
4   10     now + 4
5   10     now + 5
```

I would like to remove all non contiguous duplicates of the RecordID Column when they are sorted by DateInserted

In my example I would like to remove record 4 and 5 because between 2 and 4 there is a record with different id.

Is there a way to do it with 1 query ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use window functions.  One method is to count the changes in value that occur up to each row and just take the rows with one change:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when prev_recordid = recordid then 0 else 1 end) over (order by dateinserted) as grp_num
      from (select t.*,
                   lag(recordid) over (order by dateinserted) as prev_recordid
            from t
           ) t
     ) t
where grp_num = 1;
```

Comment: Thank you. This will i guess select them. What if I would like to remove them ?

Comment: @ClaudioFerraro . . . You would use an updatable CTE.  Just use `delete` and change the last condition to `grp_num > 1`.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to "flag" all the rows where it is *not* the first time this `RecordID` appeared *and* the prior row contained a different `RecordID`. Then you just exclude any row beyond that point for that `RecordID`.

```
;WITH cte AS 
(
  SELECT ID, RecordID, DateInserted, 
    dr    = DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY RecordID ORDER BY DateInserted),
    prior = COALESCE(LAG(RecordID,1) OVER (ORDER BY DateInserted), RecordID)
  FROM dbo.table_name
),
FlaggedRows AS 
(
  SELECT RecordID, dr
    FROM cte 
    WHERE dr > 1 AND prior <> RecordID
)
SELECT cte.ID, cte.RecordID, cte.DateInserted
  FROM cte 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN FlaggedRows AS f 
    ON cte.RecordID = f.RecordID
  WHERE cte.dr < COALESCE(f.dr, cte.dr + 1)
  ORDER BY cte.DateInserted;
```

If you want to actually *delete* the rows from the source (remove will typically be inferred as *removing from the result*), then change the `SELECT` at the end to:

```
DELETE cte
FROM cte 
  INNER JOIN FlaggedRows f 
  ON cte.RecordID = f.RecordID
  WHERE cte.dr >= f.dr;
```